# SpecFlow 3 for .NET Core test run error on build server

Tags: asp.net-core, specflow

Our TeamCity server cannot run the SpecFlow 3 tests for a .NET Core project.

My home and work workstations are able to run these tests.

It seems that during the creation of the ASP.NET Core in-memory TestServer web server instance, all the types are being enumerated as part of the DI container setup.

> Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecRun...

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException : Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecRun, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d0fc5cc18b3b389b'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecRun.Common, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d0fc5cc18b3b389b'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
...
// Abridged here
...
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer..ctor(IWebHostBuilder builder, IFeatureCollection featureCollection)
```

Searching my workstation I can find the following matching assembly.

```
FullName
--------
C:\Users\luke.puplett\.nuget\packages\specrun.runner\3.0.337\tools\net45\TechTalk.SpecRun.dll
C:\Users\luke.puplett\.nuget\packages\specrun.runner\3.0.337\tools\netcoreapp2.0\TechTalk.SpecRun.dll
C:\Users\luke.puplett\.nuget\packages\specrun.runner\3.0.337\tools\netcoreapp2.1\TechTalk.SpecRun.dll
C:\Users\luke.puplett\.nuget\packages\specrun.runner\3.0.337\tools\netcoreapp2.2\TechTalk.SpecRun.dll
```

My test project references this stuff. Note, `SpecRun.Runner` is the package that has the missing assembly though it is in `tools` above. Hmm...

```
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow" Version="3.0.199" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.0.199" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.xUnit" Version="3.0.199" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecRun.Runner" Version="3.0.337" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1">
```

I'll keep struggling on and will report back.

I removed the `feature.cs` files from Git tracking so I'm looking into the idea that these files are still on the build server, not cleaned out.

Additional query words: ci cicd pipeline

Comment: Please open an issue on https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow or https://specflow.org/specflow-support/

Comment: Thanks, I will if I can't solve it myself. I prefer to use the GitHub community as a last resort or once I've removed reasonable doubt of user error :)

Comment: Opening an issue now since it failed on another machine.

Comment: Link to the issue: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1567

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is solved in this document :

https://www.thetopsites.net/article/54438056.shtml

What you have to do this is delete one of the the runners ie SpecRun, and add  `Specflow.Tools.MSbuild.Generation` NuGet Package which will fix your  problem.